# Meteor: Installation and Drive Selection

Tags: meteor, path, installation

I have decided to jump into learning Meteor and have a few questions.
Preface: 
* Windows 10 64 bit (new laptop)
* C: Drive is where windows lives (250 GB)
* D: Drive is where the space is at (1 TB)

I used Chocalately: `Choco install Meteor`

Question(s):

1. Does Meteor have to be installed on the C: Drive under the window user localapp?  Tried to pass a path as args, it didn't work, I can live with the C: installation but strongly prefer to build projects on D:
2. Can Meteor create projects and interact with them when on the D: drive or do they always have to be local to the meteor install drive?

I can create projects on the D: drive

```
meteor create D:\simple-todos
```

(tutorial, doesn't include the json-lock though, not accurate to tutorial)

This does not seem to want to work without error

```
cd D:\simple-todos
meteor
```

Comment: Please share the error messages.

Comment: I went and posted on the Meteor forum, it began quite a discussion.  At the end of the day the answer seems to be: 1) Don't do it and 2) Be careful with Meteor and windows